# VS Code exception Cannot evaluate because of java.lang.IllegalStateException: Project cannot be found

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, debugging, web

I'm running a Java Maven Web Application in VS Code. In debug mode when watching variables I get the above exception instead of the variable value.
Say my project is named xyz, this is my launch.json:

```
{
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [        
        
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "xyz",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/xyz",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/xyz/target/xyz"
        }
      ]
    }
```

pojectName property is not allowed when using type="chrome" and in pom.xml my artifactId is xyz. It looks like the debugger knows my project name, but can't find it?
Other debug features work well. Break points hit and step-ins work.
What am I missing here?

I also tried launch.json this way, but the browser is just launched without any url and the problem is still there:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "env": {
            "hostName" : "localhost",
            "port": 8080,
            "root": "${workspaceFolder}/xyz/target/xyz",
            "projectName": "xyz"
        }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: `"type": "chrome",`? try `"type": "java",`.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `webroot` configuration and change `"type": "chrome"` to `"type": "java"`.

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Attach)",
            "request": "attach",
            "hostName": "localhost",
            "port": 8080
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly it.